# Handlebars partial displays file path instead of serving file

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I registered it

```
handlebars.registerPartial('nav', 'view/partials/nav');
```

And I called it

```
{{> "nav"}}
```

but I only get this

> view/partials/nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/#partials) arguments of `.registerPartial(arg1, arg2)` are:

1. Partial name
2. Partial content

Handlebars does not have built in functionality to serve static files from relative paths.

So without using external framework like for example the one [hapijs uses](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-views-in-hapi-9) to render views, what you can do is:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('nav',
    ('<nav>' +
    // your <nav> html
    // ...
    // ...
    </nav>')
);
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much, I was obsessing over that for almost 2 days.... you're right, I'm not using a server side language on this project so I'm going vanilla handlebars... ajaxing did the trick :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)